# Handling Location updates

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to create a page that will outlay (using Google Maps) a race circuit and will use a dot of some kind to show and update the users current location.

The code I have for this is:

```
public class TopGearLocationTracker extends FragmentActivity implements
//Specifies methods that Location Services calls when a location client 
//is connected or disconnected.//
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
//Specifies a method that Location Services calls if an error occurs while
//attempting to connect the location client. This method uses the previously-
//defined showErrorDialog method to display an error dialog that attempts to 
//fix the problem using Google Play services.
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
//The callback method that Location Services invokes to send a location update 
//to your application is specified in the LocationListener interface, in the method 
//onLocationChanged(). The incoming argument is a Location object containing the 
//location's latitude and longitude. The following snippet shows how to specify 
//the interface and define the method:
LocationListener
{
    // Global constants
    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int
            CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;


    // Global variable to hold the current location
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    private GoogleMap aMap;


    // Global constants
    // Milliseconds per second
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    // Update frequency in seconds
    public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
    // Update frequency in milliseconds
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL =
            MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
    // The fastest update frequency, in seconds
    private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
    // A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL =
            MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

    // Define an object that holds accuracy and frequency parameters
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


    // Global variables
    LocationClient mLocationClient;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.top_gear_location_tracker);    

        // Set the map up
        // Set the map to Top Gear track location
        LatLng topGearTrack = new LatLng(51.116492, -0.541767);

        aMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        aMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        aMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        aMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        aMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(topGearTrack, 15));

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(
                LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        // Open the shared preferences
        //mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences",
                //Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Get a SharedPreferences editor
        //mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

        /*
         * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
         * handle callbacks.
         */
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        // Start with updates turned off
        mUpdatesRequested = false;   
    }

    public void setUpMapIfNeeded() 
    {
        //Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (aMap == null) 
        {
            aMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                   .getMap();
        //Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (aMap != null) 
        {
            //The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called when the Activity becomes visible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    /*
     * Called when the Activity is no longer visible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }


    // *************** CHECK FOR GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES *************** //


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean servicesConnected() 
    {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.
                        isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) 
        {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d("Location Updates",
                    "Google Play services is available.");
            // Continue
            return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Get the error code
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    resultCode,
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) 
            {
                // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment =
                        new ErrorDialogFragment();
                // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
                // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                        "Location Updates");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    // Define a DialogFragment that displays the error dialog
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment 
    {
        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;
        // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
        public ErrorDialogFragment() 
        {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }
        // Set the dialog to display
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) 
        {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }
        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
     * by Google Play services
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) 
        {
            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
             * to connect again
             */
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                    /*
                     * Try the request again
                     */
                    break;
                }
        }
    }


    // ******************** CALLBACK METHODS AND INTERFACES ******************** //


    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) 
    {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // If already requested, start periodic updates
        if (mUpdatesRequested) 
        {
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() 
    {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) 
    {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try 
            {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services cancelled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } 
            catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) 
            {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) 
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(String.valueOf(errorCode))
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                }).show();
    }

    // Define the callback method that receives location updates
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        // Report to the UI that the location was updated
        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I try to load this 'page' by clicking a button from a previous page it doesn't load up. I was at least expecting the map (of Top Gear test track) to load up.

What could be stopping the map from loading up?
Is my approach to creating what I'm after correct?

I have pretty much followed:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html
(I haven't bothered with the Shared Preferences thing).

I think to test it I would be best to use my home location lat/lang but for the moment I can't get the map to appear? This was tested on my HTC One so shouldn't be a Google Play Services issue as the screen that loads this one is a static (except zoom in/out) Map of the same place.

I appreciate this is a 'large' question and I would appreciate feedback from people that have experience/created a 'location-aware' application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the article https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-map-and-geofence-features-in-android-business-apps

1. Add Android Manifest permissions:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   ```

and

```
<meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="copy your API Key here"/>
```

1. To add a map fragment:

and

```
…
private static final LatLng CHANDLER = new LatLng(33.455,-112.0668);
…
private static final StoreLocation[] ALLRESTURANTLOCATIONS = new StoreLocation[] {
    new StoreLocation(new LatLng(33.455,-112.0668), new String("Phoenix, AZ")),
    new StoreLocation(new LatLng(33.5123,-111.9336), new String("SCOTTSDALE, AZ")),
    new StoreLocation(new LatLng(33.3333,-111.8335), new String("Chandler, AZ")),
    new StoreLocation(new LatLng(33.4296,-111.9436), new String("Tempe, AZ")),
    new StoreLocation(new LatLng(33.4152,-111.8315), new String("Mesa, AZ")),
    new StoreLocation(new LatLng(33.3525,-111.7896), new String("Gilbert, AZ"))
};
…    
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.geolocation_view);

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.storelocationmap)).getMap();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CHANDLER, ZOOM_LEVEL));
    Drawable iconDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap iconBmp = ((BitmapDrawable) iconDrawable).getBitmap();
    for(int ix = 0; ix < ALLRESTURANTLOCATIONS.length; ix++) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(ALLRESTURANTLOCATIONS[ix].mLatLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconBmp)));
    }
```

Then you add the LocationListener and the location update callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will go through it in stages. I already had the permission and meta data (allow Maps) in my manifest.